# One extension for several types

Tags: dart

In project we have a lot of `enum` that need to be serializable and
deserializable in/from `String`. So I wrote the extension:

```dart
extension EnumSerializer on MyEnum {
  String getString() => this.toString().split('.').last;
  static MyEnum fromString(String str) => MyEnum.values.firstWhere( (v) => v.getString() == str, orElse: () => throw SerializerError('bad string');
}
```

But problem is I should write new extension with the same content for every enum.

Is it possible to do something like this:

```dart
extension EnumSerializer on MyEnum, OtherEnum, AnotherEnum { ...
```

Comment: Should be added that this question is also asked and discussed on the Dart language issue tracker: https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/1255

Answer (score 2):

As a direct answer to your question, no, that is not possible.

As a side note, the lack of native parsing functionality for enums is a sticking point for a lot of people. The extension approach helps, but it's hampered by both the lack of a base class for enum types (forcing an extension be made for every enum type) and the lack of support for static type extensions.

I would argue that it's saner to instead forgo extensions altogether and create a generic static utility method somewhere that can handle all enum types:

```dart
class EnumHelper {
  static String asString<T>(T value) {
    final str = value.toString();
    return str.substring(str.indexOf('.') + 1);
  }

  static T parse<T>(String str, List<T> values) {
    for (var v in values) {
      if (toString(v) == str) {
        return v;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
}

// Usage
enum Foo { a, b }

EnumHelper.asString(Foo.a); // "a"
EnumHelper.parse("a", Foo.values); // Foo.a
```

---

EDIT: As of Dart 2.15, you no longer need extension methods or custom utilities for this functionality. Enums have builtin helper methods for parsing and serializing:

```dart
enum Foo { a, b }

Foo.a.name;             // "a"
Foo.values.byName("a"); // Foo.a
Foo.values.asNameMap(); // { "a": Foo.a, "b": Foo.b }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created [feature request](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/1255) in dart repository:

> It's much more likely that we'll introduce a supertype of enums, than that we will allow an extension on multiple types.
> The latter would mean that this inside the extension cannot be typed, which is a no-go in typed language like Dart 2.

> One alternative is that If we had union types, you could do on (Type1 | Type2 | Type3) and let that union type be the type of this inside the extension. We don't have union types yet, and likely won't any time soon, it'd be a large change to the Dart type system.

> So, a "no" to multiple extension on types from me. You have to find a common supertype for them.